# Is there any way to use react-moveable in Nextjs?

Tags: next.js

I'm currently using react-moveable and react-selecto packages to build a moveable component. But it seems to be a problem with these two main packages and Nextjs.
I'm using React v18.1.0 and Next v12.1.6

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import Moveable from "react-moveable";
import Selecto from "react-selecto";

export default function MoveableProvider() {

  const [targets, setTargets] = useState([]);
  const [frameMap] = useState(() => new Map());
  const selectoRef = useRef(null);
  const moveableRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Moveable
        ref={moveableRef}
        draggable={true}
        target={targets}
        onClickGroup={(e) => {
          selectoRef.current.clickTarget(e.inputEvent, e.inputTarget);
        }}
        onDrag={(e) => {
          const target = e.target;
          const frame = frameMap.get(target);

          frame.translate = e.beforeTranslate;
          target.style.transform = `translate(${frame.translate[0]}px, ${frame.translate[1]}px)`;
        }}
        onDragStart={(e) => {
          const target = e.target;

          if (!frameMap.has(target)) {
            frameMap.set(target, {
              translate: [0, 0],
            });
          }
          const frame = frameMap.get(target);

          e.set(frame.translate);
        }}
        onDragGroupStart={(e) => {
          e.events.forEach((ev) => {
            const target = ev.target;

            if (!frameMap.has(target)) {
              frameMap.set(target, {
                translate: [0, 0],
              });
            }
            const frame = frameMap.get(target);

            ev.set(frame.translate);
          });
        }}
        onDragGroup={(e) => {
          e.events.forEach((ev) => {
            const target = ev.target;
            const frame = frameMap.get(target);

            frame.translate = ev.beforeTranslate;
            target.style.transform = `translate(${frame.translate[0]}px, ${frame.translate[1]}px)`;
          });
        }}
      />
      <Selecto
        ref={selectoRef}
        dragContainer={".elements"}
        selectableTargets={[".selecto-area .cube"]}
        hitRate={0}
        selectByClick={true}
        selectFromInside={false}
        toggleContinueSelect={["shift"]}
        ratio={0}
        onDragStart={(e) => {
          const moveable = moveableRef.current;
          const target = e.inputEvent.target;
          k;
          if (
            moveable.isMoveableElement(target) ||
            targets.some((t) => t === target || t.contains(target))
          ) {
            e.stop();
          }
        }}
        onSelectEnd={(e) => {
          const moveable = moveableRef.current;
          setTargets(e.selected);

          if (e.isDragStart) {
            e.inputEvent.preventDefault();

            setTimeout(() => {
              moveable.dragStart(e.inputEvent);
            });
          }
        }}
      ></Selecto>

      <div className="elements selecto-area" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <div
          className="cube target"
          style={{
            width: 250,
            height: 200,
            background: "green",
          }}
        ></div>

        <div
          className="cube target"
          style={{
            width: 250,
            height: 200,
            background: "yellow",
          }}
        ></div>

        <div
          className="cube target"
          style={{
            width: 250,
            height: 200,
            background: "aqua",
          }}
        ></div>

        <div
          className="cube target"
          style={{
            width: 250,
            height: 200,
            background: "red",
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div className="empty elements"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this case **onDragGroup** doesn't work for no reason in Nextjs but single drag (**onDrag**) works fine.
Is there any way that **SSR** would be causing the problem?

Comment: You can test if SSR is the issue by using dynamic import and disabling SSR - https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import